# Why does conditional formatting and dec sep align render values twice?

Tags: tables, pgfplotstable

I want to use `dec sep align` and conditional formatting at the same time. Separately I managed to make them work, but together they double every value in the column.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,pgfplotstable,colortbl}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
            columns/A/.style={%
                postproc cell content/.style={
                    /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.initial={}{
                        \pgfmathparse{int(less(##1,0))} 
                        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                        \cellcolor{green}{##1}
                        \else
                        {##1}
                        \fi
                    }
                },
                dec sep align,
            },
%           columns/.style={
%               dec sep align
%           },
            col sep=comma
            ]{          ,A,B,C,D
                1,-2.27,-32.94,134.32,-19.92
                2,3.40,13.53,106.51,11.79
                3,-116.5,-6.43,208.59,-0.11
                4,-16.47,-2.38,299.76,-9.76
                }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

which renders the following result

[image: twice rendered values]

The commented solution also doesn't work.

Ideally, I would like all columns to respect `dec sep align` and columns A, B and D to also respect conditional formatting. So far, I managed to get column A to respect conditional formatting, but only if I don't also use `dec sep align` at the same time.

Is it a bug that `dec sep align` cannot be used with conditional formatting or I just didn't get it how to use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the footnote on page 12 of the current [pgfplotstable manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplotstable.pdf). Looks like `dec sep align` doesn't play well with `\cellcolor`.

As for the double entry, the `dec sep align` option splits the entry into two columns, to which your `post proc` is applied. Using `.initial` and adding `##1` overwrites the parsed entries with the original, resulting in the double entry.
Using `add` and removing the `##1` allows the split by `doc sep align` to persist; however, the `\cellcolor` is larger than necessary and the second cell covers a bit of the first (I presume this is the overhang mentioned in the manual):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,pgfplotstable,colortbl,siunitx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h!]
            \pgfplotstabletypeset[%
            columns/A/.style={
                postproc cell content/.style={
                    /pgfplots/table/@cell content/.add={}{
                        \pgfmathparse{int(less(##1,0))} 
                        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=1
                        \cellcolor{green}
                        \fi
                    }
                },
                dec sep align={c}},
            columns/B/.style={dec sep align={c}},
            columns/C/.style={dec sep align={c}},
            columns/D/.style={dec sep align={c}},
            col sep=comma
            ]{          ,A,B,C,D
                1,-2.27,-32.94,134.32,-19.92
                2,3.40,13.53,106.51,11.79
                3,-116.5,-6.43,208.59,-0.11
                4,-16.47,-2.38,299.76,-9.76
                }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `/.append code` is the shorthand for `/.add={}{...}`